# Fazer borda -1 utilizando erode e dilate (Python)

Tags: python, opencv

Estou com dificuldade na criação de uma borda com pixeis -1 em volta do que foi rotulado na imagem. Onde 255 é o que foi rotulado e em volta dessa área de 255 quero colocar -1 que sera uma borda a ser ignorada no treinamento. Estou tentando utilizar erode na imagem .png e depois utilizar dilation em cima do erode, para criar essa borda, porem não consigo de modo algum modificar o valor que a borda criada por eles receberá. Tentei utilzar borderType, porem não foi efetivo.

Segue o código atual:

```
import cv2

import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('frame22.png',0)

kernel = np.ones((5,5),np.uint8)

erosion = cv2.erode(img,kernel,iterations = 1)

dilationcomerosion = cv2.dilate(erosion,kernel,iterations = 1)

cv2.namedWindow("Input", cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)

cv2.namedWindow("dilationcomerosion", cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)

cv2.imshow('Input', img)

cv2.imshow('dilationcomerosion', erosion)

cv2.waitKey(0)
```

[image: Segue imagem do array da variável apos a execução do dilate em cima do erosion:]

[image: Input]

[image: Dilate em cima do Erode]

[image: frame22.png]

Comment: Favor [edit] a pergunta com a imagem "frame22.png". E achei confuso, o que seria -1? -1 nas coordenadas? No algoritmo de erode? No canal de cor de cada pixel?

Comment: Favor ler [Como devemos formatar perguntas e respostas?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1084/75104)

Comment: Gostaria de que o valor na coordenada fosse alterado para -1, em resumo ser criado uma borda de -1 ao redor do que foi rotulado com 255, portando imagino que seja melhor ser alterado o valor da coordenada de 0 apra -1.

Comment: As coordenadas são os eixos x e y, são os números 500 e poucos na sua imagem. Já o 0 e 255 é a cor em binário de cada pixel, em que 0 é preto e 255 branco. Por isso que ao colocar -1 neste canal de cor, o OpenCV retornará um erro. Pois no OpenCV o intervalo de cores binárias é 0 ou 255... Porém, você pode alterar estes valores no numpy e visualizar no PyCharm ou em outra biblioteca como a `matplotlib.pyplot`

Comment: No caso então para fazer o que eu preciso, é necessário alterar o valor da coordenada mesmo né? Pois como não existe valor de cor -1 dará erro. Consigo realizar essa mudança com essa biblioteca informada?

Comment: A coordenada é a posição de cada pixel numa matriz, ou seja, (x,y) e cada pixel possui as seguintes informações (x,y, cores). Em que cores varia de acordo com o espaço de cores utilizado, se for binário possui somente um canal. Mas se for colorido no espaço de cores RGB, por exemplo, cores será [R,G,B]. Creio que sua pergunta está confusa pois você não entendeu muito bem como funciona visão computacional, tente estudar a parte básica e teórica para entender melhor.

Comment: Sim eu sei, entendi sim o que quis dizer, porem acho que você não conseguiu entender com clareza a minha pergunta, sei que cada pixel é seguido de (x,y, cor). a intenção real é simplesmente conseguir fazer uma borda que virá a ser ignorada no treinamento, portanto eu teria que modificar esse valor para -1 que é o valor ignorado no algoritmo de treinamento, mas não consigo encontrar opções de como realizar a criação dessa borda a ser ignorada, tanto que perdi muito tempo em erode, dilate e gradient.para tentar de alguma forma criar essa borda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Problema

As imagens são carregadas pelo OpenCV como unit8, para mais informações sobre tipos de dados ler [este link do Numpy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.types.html).

Portanto, eles são unsigned int, ou seja, não possuem sinal (número negativo). Então ao substituir o valor da matriz por -1, o Python automaticamente considera -1 como 255, -2 como 254 e assim por diante.

Para resolver isso, é necessário converter a matriz para outro tipo de dado.

#### Código

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
import urllib.request


def mostrar_imagem(img):
    plt.imshow(img)
    plt.colorbar()
    plt.show()

#Inicialização
# Carregar imagem da internet
resp = urllib.request.urlopen("https://i.stack.imgur.com/gVDrL.png")
img = np.asarray(bytearray(resp.read()), dtype="uint8")
img = cv2.imdecode(img, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

# Converte para escala de cinza
cinza = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
# Obtém o binário
_, binario = cv2.threshold(cinza, 90, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
# Cria uma cópia para manter a original
copia = img.copy()

#procurar os contornos, procura contornos dentro dos contornos, aproxima os contornos
tmp = cv2.findContours(binario, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
# compatibilidade entre versões diferentes do OpenCV
contornos = tmp[0] if len(tmp) == 2 else tmp[1]
#retorna 3 parametros, 1)imagens, 2contornos,3) hierarquia dos contornos

#Conversão de escala de cinza para BGR
img_contornos = cv2.cvtColor(cinza, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)

#Desenha os contornos
#imagem, contornos, (-1) são todos, a cor, espessura
cv2.drawContours(img_contornos, contornos, -1, (0, 255, 0), 1)
mostrar_imagem(img_contornos)

# Extrai somente o contorno de espessura 1 px
mask = cv2.inRange(img_contornos, (0, 254, 0), (0, 255, 0))
mostrar_imagem(mask)

# Substitui os valores da máscara por -1
binario = np.int16(binario)
binario[mask == 255] = -1

# Mostrar os valores -1 como cor branca
binario = np.ma.masked_where(binario == -1, binario)
cmap = matplotlib.cm.Greys  # Can be any colormap that you want after the cm
cmap.set_bad(color='red')
plt.imshow(binario, cmap=cmap)
plt.show()
```

#### Explicação

1. Carrega a imagem;
2. Converte a imagem para binário, pois o `findcontours` utiliza um algoritmo para imagens com um canal de cor;
3. Encontra os contornos da imagem;
4. Desenha o contorno com 1 pixel de espessura: [image: Contorno]
5. Cria uma máscara com a extração dos contornos: [image: Máscara]
6. Converte a imagem para int16;
7. Substitui por -1 na imagem binária, os pixels que possuírem valor igual a 255 na imagem da máscara.
8. Altera os pixels com valor igual a -1 para a cor vermelha no visualizador da biblioteca matplotlib.

[image: Resultado]

Comment: Para ler um arquivo direto da pasta onde está o código por exemplo, utilizando o cv2, consigo fazer img.imread("nome_do_arquivo",0), tentei utilizar assim, porem não funcionou, você indica alguma outra função que faça isso, no caso mudar:
resp = urllib.request.urlopen("https://i.stack.imgur.com/gVDrL.png")
img = np.asarray(bytearray(resp.read()), dtype="uint8")

por alguma função que eu consiga ler da pasta a imagem ao invés do url e esse código continuar funcionando. 
Acho que esse código resolve bem o meu problema (pois consegui aplicar erode e dilate sobre ele, melhorou bastante).

Comment: Em qual formato estão as suas imagens, tomei como padrão a que você enviou. Mas se já estiverem em binário, você não precisa convertê-las para o espaço de cores binário.

Comment: As imagens estão em formato PNG.

Comment: Quando você lê a imagem com`imread(img, 0)` você está criando uma matriz no espaço de cor em escala de cinza. Como se fosse `cinza` no código

Comment: Entendi, e você sugere alguma outra função que leia o arquivo da pasta, mas que esse código que você enviou continue funcionando? Tentei algumas, mas sem sucesso.
#resp = cv2.imread("frame22.png", 0)
#resp = plt.imread('frame22.png')
#resp = Image.open('frame22.png')
#resp = plt.imread("frame22.png", format=None) #esse consegue ler, ams da erro no read do bytearray
#resp = mpimg.imread("frame22.png")

Comment: Tente `cinza = cv2.imread("frame22.png", 0)` e retire a outra parte do código. Como eu disse antes, creio que você não entendeu a parte básica de visão computacional. Veja um pouco da parte incial, vale a pena, pois os espaços de cores e os tipos de dados você terá que entender em qualquer aplicação que for realizar com imagens.

Comment: Certo, vou dar uma olhada nisso, ainda to bem no começo, por isso tem algumas coisas que ainda não sei bem.

Comment: Tentei a alteração sugerida, mas mesmo assim ele me retorna erro no bytearray(resp.read()) que alterei para bytearray(cinza.read()), ou essa parte também não é necessaria?
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'read'

Comment: Fiz uma alterações aqui e deu certo de ler o arquivo PNG direto da pasta.
img = cv2.imread('frame22.png',0)
#remover o cinza, pois ele ja esta em escala de cinza lido pelo .imread()
# Converte para escala de cinza
#cinza = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
_, binario = cv2.threshold(img, 90, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
img_contornos = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)

Essas foram as alterações que fiz, que deu certo e obtive o mesmo resultado.